# Can I ask questions about sufisim?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it allowed to ask questions about sufisim and Sufi sages(like Rumi) on the website.

Will my question be answered

Comment: It would depend on the existence of users being able to answer. I personally have nothing against sufism.

Comment: I think it is allowed because sufisim is also a part of Islam

Comment: All sorts of questions that actually are related to Islam, whether it be regarding Salafi, Sufi, Shia, or any sect at all are all valid questions here.